# Let $\text{T} = \mathbb{Q}(i)^\times/\mathbb{Q}^\times$ compute $\text{T}(\mathbb{A})/\text{T}(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-groups, locally-compact-groups, adeles

I have a question about algebraic tori, let $T = \mathbb{Q}(i)^\times/\mathbb{Q}^\times$ and let's try to compute $\text{T}(\mathbb{A})/\text{T}(\mathbb{Q})$.

One has a product decomposition for the multiplicative group of Gaussian integers:
$$  \mathbb{Q}(i)^\times \simeq \mathbb{Z} \times \prod_{p=4k+1}\mathbb{Z}^2 \times \prod_{p = 4k+3}\mathbb{Z}$$
This has to do with Fermat's theorem that $p = a^2 + b^2$ iff $p = 4k+1$.  In that case, with we factor out the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Q}$ we'd have something like:
$$ \mathbb{Q}(i)^\times / \mathbb{Q}^\times \simeq \prod_{p=4k+1} \mathbb{Z}$$
This does not say much about a topolog of $\mathbf{T}$ as a locally compact Abelian group. E.g. this is infinitly generated.  We could consider this as a $2 \times 2$ matrix group with elements in $\mathbb{Q}$:

$$ \mathbb{Q}(i)^\times / \mathbb{Q}^\times \simeq  \prod_{p=4k+1} \left( \begin{array}{cr} a & -b \\ b & a \end{array} \right)^\mathbb{Z} $$
This is my best guess, and hopefully that's more informative.

Given all this work, Can we give some kind of matrix way of looking at $\mathbf{T}(\mathbb{A})/\mathbf{T}(\mathbb{Q})$ ?

Comment: Usually to talk about $T(\mathbb A)$ and $T(\mathbb Q)$, $T$ should be a group scheme over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Also, I think your description of $\mathbb Q(i)^{\ast}$ is that of the group of fractional ideals, you should mod out by the units to get it

Comment: @D_S Try $\text{T}=\text{Res}_{\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{G_m})/\mathbb{G_m}$ where $\mathbb{G_m}$ is the [multiplicative group](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/022U) functor and and $\text{Res}_{K/L}$ is [restriction of scalars](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05Y8) for number fields $K$ and $L$.

Comment: Starting off, $\mathbb G_m$ is a closed subgroup of $\operatorname{Res}_{\mathbb Q(i)/\mathbb Q}(\mathbb G_m)$ by $x \mapsto (x,x)$, so we have an exact sequence

$$1 \rightarrow \mathbb G_m \rightarrow \operatorname{Res}_{\mathbb Q(i)/\mathbb Q}(\mathbb G_m) \rightarrow T \rightarrow 1 $$
On points we get an exact sequence

$$1 \rightarrow \mathbb Q^{\ast} \rightarrow \mathbb Q(i)^{\ast} \rightarrow T(\mathbb Q) \rightarrow H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q),\overline{\mathbb Q}^{\ast})$$ So my first thought in approaching this is to determine whether $H^1$ is trivial

Comment: That is, can we identify $T(\mathbb Q)$ as $\mathbb Q(i)^{\ast}/\mathbb Q^{\ast}$?

Comment: When restricting to the finite adeles then $T(\mathbb{A}_{fin})/T(\mathbb{Q})\cong W(Gal(\mathbb{Q}(i)^{ab}/\mathbb{Q}^{ab})$ with $W$ the Weil group. Describing it should be possible in term of the group of torsion points of the elliptic curve $y^2= x^3+x$ with CM by $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and the embedding of the group of roots in unity in one of its quotient.